# How to configure nginx proxy_pass based on dynamic url param?

Tags: nginx, parameters, arguments

Normally when I use **http://127.0.0.1/apiset/some_dynamc_string** and I get the json file.

The **/apiset/** is the directory where my app resides. The “some_dynamc_string” its a dynamic request string. I install nginx to my ubuntu 18.04. my domain is cep.myname.com when I run **http://cep.myname.com** I get the default nginx page.

I configure the **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** (I also set the sites-enabled) as;

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name cep.myname.com;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
    }
}
```

I get an **404** error. I need my user sends the “some_dynamc_string” as:

```
http://cep.myname.com/apiset/some_dynamc_string
```

And I need to use proxy_pass so I can send the  **“/apiset/some_dynamc_string”** to my backend as:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/apiset/some_dynamc_string;

How do I do that? How to configure nginx proxy_pass based on dynamic url param as I describe above?

```
When I use error_log with debug I get this:
2018/10/10 08:28:23 [error] 19170#19170: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/apiset/some_dynamc_string" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 12.11.10.10, server: localhost, request: "GET /apiset/some_dynamc_string HTTP/1.1", host: "cep.myname.com"
```

I guess my problem starts in here: In "/usr/share/nginx/html/apiset/some_dynamc_string" I don't have the "/apiset/some_dynamc_string". I have only index.html the default nginx html file. The "apiset/some_dynamc_string" is for my backend server.

When client sends this: http://cep.myname.com/apiset/some_dynamc_string
it redirects to"/usr/share/nginx/html/apiset/some_dynamc_string". I need to configure to send to "http://127.0.0.1:8888/apiset/some_dynamc_string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found it. I use default.conf in sites-available and sites-enabled. this was wrong place to modify default.conf. Correct path is modify default.conf in conf.d dir.

```
1) install nginx
2) run: 
    nginx -v  
    (nginx version: nginx/1.15.5)
3) sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

    server {
        listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            error_log    /var/log/nginx/your_domain_name.error.log debug;
            rewrite_log on;

            server_name your_domain_name;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
        }
    }


4) sudo systemctl reload nginx
5) sudo systemctl restart nginx
6) sudo nginx -t
7) curl http://your_domain_name/
```